# Excel relative cell hyperlink

Tags: excel

I have a workbook with sheet1 and sheet 2, sheet1 cell A1 pulls info from sheet2 cell C1, so for easy editing I have hyperlinked sheey2!C1 in sheet1 cell A1.

My issue is that when i delete rows/columbs in sheet 2, the hyperlink does not adapt accordingly and then pull the wrong data, any ways around this?

Comment: What happens to the hyperlink in sheet 1 if the location it's pointing to has been deleted already?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to create your hyperlink:

`=HYPERLINK(link_location[, friendly_name])`

Example:

`=HYPERLINK(Sheet2!A2, "A2")`

In the given example, if the first row is deleted, the formula is automatically changed to `=HYPERLINK(Sheet2!A1, "A2")`